# request to https://registry.npmjs.org/solc failed, reason: certificate has expired

Tags: npm-install

request to https://registry.npmjs.org/solc failed, reason: certificate has expired

Installed node js and trying npm install -g solc for first time. I am not able to download anything . tried all options. I am behind company network vpn and i can access https://registry.npmjs.org/solc in all browsers. Trying for last 3 days.

Can anyone please advise.

Comment: Given that you get the 'expired' message my best guess is that your company is not just using a VPN, but they actively intercept and break the internet for you. This sounds like a question for your IT department, not stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 queries here:
1. I am trying npm install for ist time- if the url https://registry.npmjs.org/ works in browser, will it not be right to conclude that it should work with npm install? basically nothing is working with npm install.

2. I disconnected vpn and removed all proxy settings from laptop and its now on open network, it still does not work. Any suggestions.

Comment: A reason why it *could* be different between browser and CLI is because they could use different certification stores. One more thing to check though.. is your computer date/time correct? that could also cause this

Comment: Thanks Evert. I did computer restart. Un checked everything and cleared all settings/disabled vpn.

i did npm install now and it worked.
got below output:
added 26 packages from 18 contributors in 18.596s

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!